# Statsmodels: How to fit an AR-like model using multiple time series as input?

Tags: regression, statsmodels, arima

I have been stuck for days because I cannot find a way to fit a traditional regression model such as ARIMA giving multiple time series as input.

I have got thousand trajectories positions of different vehicles (xy coordinates for each position). Let's say each sample (trajectory) is composed of 10 positions (all objects trajectories are not necessarily of the same length). It means I have got 10*N different time series (N is the total number of samples). I want to fit a model with all samples for x coordinates and then predict the future position of any new trajectory (test samples) that I give in input. Then I plan to do the same with another model for y coordinates. I do not say the method will work but I need to implement it to compare it with others (Neural networks, ...)

The hypothesis: a number of time series can be modeled with a single ARIMAX (or other) model (i.e. the same parameters work for all the time series). What is wanted: to fit them all simultaneously.

Can someone help me please?
Thank you in advance for your support!
Best regards,